# How To Use RegEx inside of Google Sheets within IF statements to only find specific zip codes (not all zip codes adhering to format)?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a column of addresses within Google Sheets formatted as:

> "1234 Western Ave, Cincinnati 45226"
>
> "5678 Eastern Ave, Columbus 45126"

and I wish to use regex within a second google sheets column to identify only zip codes beginning with 452.

I've tried search for regex within an IF statement:

```
=if( search( "regex", A1), "success message", "fail message")
```

and I've tried regex match within an if statement.

```
=if( REGEXMATCH("A1","regex"), "success message", "fail message")
```

I've tried numerous regex expressions including the following, they all validate within regex101 and various online testers - just never inside of Google sheets where I need them to. I could use some community assistance.

RegEx that works online but not in Google Sheets:

1.

```
452(\d{2})
```

2.

```
\b452\b(\d{2})
```

and so on.

How do I find only US zip codes beginning with a specific initial three digits?

Answer (score 2):

`=if( REGEXMATCH(A1,"452(\d{2})"), "success message", "fail message")`

Notes:

- `A1` is not quoted
- I suggest regex `"452\d{2}$"`. It uses `$` char to check the end of a string.

---

**EDIT:**

if you have a number, convert it into text like this: `TO_TEXT(A2)`. The formula should be:

`=if( REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A2),"452(\d{2})"), "success message", "fail message")`

Comment: You're correct that I neglected to place the cell reference within quotation marks. Thank you. 

Your suggested regex, however does not work. Any further suggestion perhaps?

Comment: hi, @user3846962, I suggest you share your sample file, to show the data and case when the regex does not work.

Comment: Sample sheet
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DuXxPU_KqpOhkO0Kkpp8qyaZFFZndnIOMHXs0pJHcY0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi, @user3846962, got you, it was a number, I was not aware of this because sample string was I "5678 Eastern Ave, Columbus 45126".

Answer (score 1):

Regexextract function might work -

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "452\d{2}")
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting an alternate regex formula, however it would not have the outcome I am looking for. Also a key component to my initial question centered around my current regex structure not working. Searching for 452\d{2} does not seem to qualify as being able to find 45231 for instance. Perhaps you have an alternate regex structure to recommend that is Google Sheets friendly?

Comment: I can't comment directly on Max's answer above since I don't have a high enough reputation yet, but I tried his out in Google Sheets and it works long as your input column doesn't literally have quotation marks in it.  If it is formatted as plain text or automatic it works.  If you do literally have quotation marks in your input column, then take out the $ at the end of Max's suggestion and it will still work.  Good luck.